# how to make the icon on a data table clickable in lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

We are trying to extend the data table in lwc where in earlier we are using the default row actions but now we want the icons to be included like edit,  delete. But I am not sure on how to make them clickable, any suggestions?

Below is the code on how we are displaying the icons

Columns being passed from design attribute:-

```
[{"label":"Actions","cellAttributes":{"iconName":"utility:edit"}},
{"fieldName": "Comments__c","label":"Comments","type": "Text"}]
```

Can we make the cell attributes clickable? If so how ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `button-icon` with the column configuration like this.

```
{
    type: 'button-icon',
    typeAttributes:
    {
        iconName: 'utility:delete',
        name: 'delete',
        iconClass: 'slds-icon-text-error'
    }
},
{
    type: 'button-icon',
    typeAttributes:
    {
        iconName: 'utility:edit',
        name: 'edit'
    }
}
```

Also, you can handle the row actions like this.

```
handleRowAction(event) {
    if (event.detail.action.name === 'delete') {
        this.deleteSelectedRow(event.detail.row);
    } else if (event.detail.action.name === 'edit') {
        this.editMode = true;
        this.openEditForm(event.detail.row);
    }
}
```

You can check this [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/fEYzYlVc/103/edit) for more details

This will add buttons like below
[image]

Comment: Hi Rahul! I was trying to implement something similar and cannot achieve it. Cannot access the playground link you mentioned. Can you please share the complete code snippet? Thank you.

Comment: @Nishant Singh Panwar here is the [sample code](https://github.com/rahulgawale/Add-Delete-Row-in-Lightning-Datatable-Lwc)

Comment: This should be marked as best answer. 